# " parameter count mismatch" QT c++

Tags: c++, qt

when i tried my code fir the first time 
it was

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QMessageBox"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPixmap pix("C:/Users/AMR.EngAmr/Downloads/1561136.jpg");
    ui->label_pic->setPixmap(pix);


        if(!connOpen())
                ui->label_9->setText("فشل الاتصال بقاعدة البيانات");
        else
            ui->label_9->setText("تم الاتصال بقاعدة البيانات ");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString Name,period,group,Weight,Notes,Notes2,Notes3,pressure;
    Name=ui->lineEdit_name->text();
    period=ui->lineEdit_2->text();
    group=ui->lineEdit_group->text();
  Weight=ui->lineEdit_weight->text();
   Notes2=ui->lineEdit_notes2->text();
  pressure=ui->lineEdit_presure->text();
  Notes=ui->lineEdit_notes->text();
   Notes3=ui->lineEdit_notes3->text();
if(!connOpen()){
    qDebug()<<"Faield to open the database";
    return;
   }
   connOpen();
   QSqlQuery qry;
 qry.prepare("insert into Patients (Name,period,group,Weight,Notes2,pressure,Notes,Notes3 ) values('"+Name+"','"+period+"''"+group+"','"+Weight+"','"+Notes2+"','"+pressure+"','"+Notes+"''"+Notes3+"')");

   if(qry.exec())
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Save"),tr("Saved"));
        connClose();
    }
    else
    {
         QMessageBox::information(this,tr("error::"),qry.lastError().text());

        }
}
```

and i got error No query Unable to fetch row
and i tried a solution and my code was

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "QMessageBox"
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QPixmap pix("C:/Users/AMR.EngAmr/Downloads/1561136.jpg");
    ui->label_pic->setPixmap(pix);


        if(!connOpen())
                ui->label_9->setText("فشل الاتصال بقاعدة البيانات");
        else
            ui->label_9->setText("تم الاتصال بقاعدة البيانات ");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString Name,period,group,Weight,Notes,Notes2,Notes3,pressure;
    Name=ui->lineEdit_name->text();
    period=ui->lineEdit_2->text();
    group=ui->lineEdit_group->text();
  Weight=ui->lineEdit_weight->text();
   Notes2=ui->lineEdit_notes2->text();
  pressure=ui->lineEdit_presure->text();
  Notes=ui->lineEdit_notes->text();
   Notes3=ui->lineEdit_notes3->text();
if(!connOpen()){
    qDebug()<<"Faield to open the database";
    return;
   }
   connOpen();
   QSqlQuery qry;
 qry.prepare("insert into Patients (:Name,:period,:group,:Weight,:Notes2,:pressure,:Notes,:Notes3 ) values('"+Name+"','"+period+"''"+group+"','"+Weight+"','"+Notes2+"','"+pressure+"','"+Notes+"''"+Notes3+"')");
 qry.bindValue(":Name", Name);
 qry.bindValue(":period", period);
 qry.bindValue(":group", group);
 qry.bindValue(":Weight", Weight);
 qry.bindValue(":Notes2", Notes2);
 qry.bindValue(":pressure", pressure);
 qry.bindValue(":Notes", Notes);
 qry.bindValue(":Note3", Notes3);

   if(qry.exec())
    {
        QMessageBox::information(this,tr("Save"),tr("Saved"));
        connClose();
    }
    else
    {
         QMessageBox::information(this,tr("error::"),qry.lastError().text());

        }
}
```

and i got the error
parameter count mismatch
what is the problem i have to finish it in two days

Comment: Hint for indentation: in Qt Creator, press ctrl-a ctrl-i.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're mixing up your value binding. When you use that, you don't put the values into the query (the very purpose of binding values is avoid that!). This might work, if the column names are correct:

```
qry.prepare("insert into Patients "
            "(Name,period,group,Weight,Notes2,pressure,Notes,Notes3) " 
            "values(:Name,:period,:group,:Weight,:Notes2,:pressure,:Notes,:Notes3)");
```

(Note about splitting strings like that, which you probably are not familiar with: in C and C++ writing `"foo" "bar"` is same as `"foobar"`.)

Also, [documentation is your friend](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#approaches-to-binding-values). Qt has mostly quite good documentation, and in this case it seems to *exactly* cover what you are asking.

Comment: @AmrSalem No problem. Note that the usual way to say "thanks"at SO is to upvote (that arrrowhead pointing up above a posts score) :-)